# Adding operationfilter to swashbuckle causes webrole to recycle continuously

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swashbuckle

We have an asp.net web api project deployed to an Azure Cloud Service (classic) that has been running fine using Swashbuckle for almost a year. We configure it like so...

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
.EnableSwagger(c =\>
{
c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "PartnerAPI");
c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
}).EnableSwaggerUi(c =\> { });
```

Recently we needed to tweak the swagger generated output by plugging in an IOperationFilter. However our Azure Cloud Service (Classic) instance will not start if we create a class that implements the IOperationFilter. We don't even try to configure Swagger to use it. Just the fact that there is a class that implements that interface in our solution causes the deploy to fail stating...

2016-12-29T16:10:26.1066042Z ##[error]BadRequest : Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent the role instances from running. Verify your code does not throw unhandled exceptions and that your configuration settings are correct and then start another update or upgrade operation.

Everything runs fine on my machine, directly and in the azure emulator
Everything runs fine on teammates machine same as above
The following message appears to be related in the event logs on the azure machine when I rdp into it.
File Server Resource Manager was unable to access the following file or volume: 'E:'. This file or volume might be locked by another application right now, or you might need to give Local System access to it.

Same problem in Swashbuckle versions 5 and 5.5
No new nuget packages or references to the project
Only a "using Swashbuckle.Swagger;' that was added to the SwaggerConfig.cs
The Azure Portal reports the following for the "Instance Status Message"...
[12/29T16:43Z]Failed to load role entrypoint. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information. at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly entryPointAssembly) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly entryPointAssembly) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.CreateRoleEntryPoint(RoleType roleTypeEnum) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)' Last exit time: [2016/12/29, 16:43:59.525]. Last exit code: 0.